# Redundancy for Selenium Hubs

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, high-availability, master-slave

I am running a large Selenium Grid and trying to achieve high availability. Currently I have a single point of failure at the Hub - if this machine goes down then my Grid goes down. I want to achieve redundancy.

I'm looking for approaches which people take to solve this problem. The hub is stateful so I cannot load balance. Is the best I can achieve a master/slave failover?

Are there packaged solutions for this?

If not - any tips for mitigating the impact of such a failover (what logic to trigger the failover? how to minimize time for nodes to connect to new hub?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a VIP?

Comment: I'm not too worried about doing the failover. The problem is that if I use something like a VIP to fail over - the nodes seem to maintain their persistent connection with the failing hub while tests get routed to the new hub. I can't possibly be the first person to deal with this redundancy problem. Or maybe I am - and people who rely on Selenium a lot use many small grids instead of a few large fortified grids?

Comment: Hmmm.. I can see how that would be an issue, I'm wondering if there's a way to force the nodes to restart or re-establish their connection.

Comment: There is a commandline option "registerCycle". But I'm hoping for approaches which result in better fidelity that that ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a Apache load balancer configured as a proxy to have a master-slave failover.  It should work great although the configuration is a little tough.